# MySQL query via Node.js with an unknown number of null parameters

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) MySQL plugin for Node.js. Here's a very simple query:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first = ? AND last = ?", [req.query.first, req.query.last], function(error, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Now here's the problem: what if only **some** of the query parameters are defined, **but not all of them**? This is a very common use case, so I'm guessing there is an elegant way to account for this, but this is all I can seem to come up with:

```
var query;
if (first && !last) {
    query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE first = ?";
} else if (!first && last) {
    query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE last = ?";
} else if (first && last) {
    query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE first = ? AND last = ?";
}
db.query(query, [req.query.first, req.query.last], function(error, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Writing a separate query for every possible combination is obviously a crude way to do it, and really isn't very practical if there are more than just a couple query parameters. Is there a more elegant (i.e. concise) way to account for an unknown number of null parameters?

**UPDATE**

This is what ended up working for me:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (:first IS NULL || first = :first) AND (:last IS NULL || last = :last)", {first: req.query.first, last: req.query.last}, function(error, results) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a bit cumbersome but you can use this query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (? IS NULL || first = ?) AND (? IS NULL || last = ?)";
```

Just be sure at least one parameter is not null (either in the query or in js).

ETA: If you use the named parameter format (:param instead of ?) this will save you some repetition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Build the query dynamically. Something like:

```
var params = ["first", "last"];
var conds = [];
var args = [];
var i;
for (i = 0 ; i < params.length ; i++)
{
    var p = params[i];
    if (req.query[p] !== undefined)
    {
        conds.push(p+'=?');
        args.push(req.query[p]);
    }
}
var query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE '+conds.join(' AND ');
db.query(query,args, etc.);
```

You'll need to handle the case where there are no conditions (you'll have to pick whether all or none match).